# How to put the same data in two panels?

Tags: c#, panel, tabcontrol

I have two panels on two different tabs of a tabControl.

This is the code to draw a "data visualization" on `panel2` in tab2.

```
chart2 = new Chart();
ChartArea chartArea2 = new ChartArea();
chart2.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea2);

series1.Points.Add(100);
chart2.Series.Add(series1);
chart2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
chart2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(panel2.Width, panel2.Height);

this.panel2.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.chart2 });
```

I want to draw the same content on `panel1` too.
But it can't draw the "data visualization" on both of panels even if I use this code:

```
chart2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
this.panel1.Controls.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.Control[] { this.chart2 });
```

I need something like this:

```
panel1 = panel2;
```

I want panel1 to be just like panel2;

Comment: A control can only belong to a single container control.

Comment: Thanks, How can I do it? What is your suggestion?

Comment: I need something like this: panel1 = panel2;

Comment: You can do it by intercepting an suitable event when changing tabs and then relocate the control from current panel to the panel being activated.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have to identical panels as far as the visualization controls are concerned.

You will then set / initialize the data properties on both controls.

The reason you need to do this is because (as Dan-o pointed out) a control can not belong to more than one container control.

Comment: Would you please put some codes for me? I'm starter.

Comment: If you know how to add one control to a tab panel then you just do it twice - make a second control and add it to the other panel. Simple.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will do that. Maybe my English is poor :)